# What is the process called, when a doctor tries to figure out what is wrong with you?

Tags: terminology

I know that *anamnesis* is the process of asking potentially relevant questions for building a medical history of a patient. I think this involves:

- Getting to know past illnesses of the patient
- Getting to know which illnesses are in the patient's family
- Asking for previous medication

But once the doctor has the history, is there a word for the process of figuring out the symptoms why a patient visited the doctor in the first place?

I imagine that doctors check the following in this process:

- Does the patient have any pain? If so, at which location and how severe is it?
- Are there other inconveniences, such as:

  - coughing
  - not getting enough air
  - running nose
  - pressure on the ear
  - feeling dizzy
  - feeling confused
  - ...

(Reason for this question: I wanted to have a look if there are books on Amazon which help in this process for people from foreign countries. So people needing a doctor, but being unable to describe properly with words what is going on)

Comment: Diagnosis  is when the doctor determines the reason for your symptoms

Answer (score 3):

**Anamnesis** = **patient's medical history** = a summary of all **symptoms** and all other relevant data (family history, circumstances in which the problems started, etc.) that a patient reveals. So, all examples mentioned in your question fall under anamnesis.

The subject that describes how to perform an anamnesis and physical examination is called **clinical propedeutics**. Various books for doctors and nurses are available, but this may be way beyond what someone needs to know from a patient's perspective.

There are numerous layman "family health" books available...

Online sources:

- [Symptoms and Signs A-Z List (MedicineNet)](https://www.medicinenet.com/symptoms_and_signs/alpha_a.htm)
- [A medical history questionnaire (Mont Sinai Medical Center)](https://www.mountsinai.org/static_files/MSH/Files/Patient%20Care/Executive%20Health%20Program/MedicalHistoryQuestionaire.pdf)